# Binary Search Method Array Java

Tags: java, reflection, binary-search, comparator, comparable

I am trying to efficiently search weather a subclass implements a method that I have the name of in a string called `_szMethodName`. I can get an array of all the methods that the subclass implements by doing `Method[] _arrClassMethodsList = class.getMethods();`. I can then compare the name of the method to the stringName of the function that I am looking for to determine weather or not the class implements that particular method. Currently I have this working in a for loop but this gets slow as the subclass grows.

For Loop implementation:

```
for (Method method : class.getMethods()){
       if(method.getName().equals(_szMethodName)){
          //method exists in subclass
          break;
      }
}
```

<s>The array of methods from  `class.getMethods()` is sorted alphabetically.</s>(Only in Java >=7).  I was hoping that I could leverage this by using a binary-search or some other optimization on the array instead of using the for loop. However, I have not yet been able to figure out how to implement Java's binary search function on the array. I have tried using comparator or and comparable but have not yet had success. My most recent implementation of comparator is below but has errors that I have not yet been able to resolve.

Current attempt using comparator:

```
Comparator<Method> c = new Comparator <Method>() {
    public int compare(Method method, String string) {
        return method.getName().compareTo(string);
    }
};

Method[] _arrClassMethodsList = class.getMethods();
int index = Arrays.binarySearch(_arrClassMethodsList, _szMethodName, c);
```

Any help or examples on how to get this working would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The Javadoc of [`getMethods()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethods%28%29) says the order is implementation dependent (The javadoc explicitly says _"The elements in the array returned are not sorted and are not in any particular order"_). I believe that in Java 7 it is alphabetical, but I believe in Java 6 it used to be definition order. So don't depend on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that the only real way to do this is to re-implement Binary search pulling out the method name during the search. My final implementation is below. Thanks for all the help everyone.

```
public final Method NOT_FOUND = null;
private Method findMethodInDelegateClassWithParameters (String _szMethodName)
{
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    Class _cDelegateClass = m_oDelegate.getClass();

    //Get and sort array for binary search if not done, ensure methods are alphabetical before Java 7 
    if (_arrSortedMethods==null){
        _arrSortedMethods = _cDelegateClass.getMethods();   
        Arrays.sort(_arrSortedMethods, new Comparator<Method>() {
               public int compare(Method m1, Method m2) {
                   return m1.getName().compareTo(m2.getName());
               }
        });
    }

    return binarySearchForMethodNamed(_arrSortedMethods, _szMethodName);
}

public Method binarySearchForMethodNamed(Method[] _arrMethods, String _szMethodName) {
    int left = 0;
    int right = _arrMethods.length - 1;
    return binarySearchMethods(_arrMethods, _szMethodName, left, right);
    }

private Method binarySearchMethods(Method[] _arrMethods, String _szMethodName, int left, int right) {
    if (right < left) {
            return NOT_FOUND;
    }

    int mid = (left + right) >>> 1;
    String _szArrayMethodName = _arrMethods[mid].getName();
    if (_szMethodName.compareTo(_szArrayMethodName)>0) {
            return binarySearchMethods(_arrMethods, _szMethodName, mid + 1, right);
    } else if (_szMethodName.compareTo(_szArrayMethodName)<0) {
            return binarySearchMethods(_arrMethods, _szMethodName, left, mid - 1);
    } else {
            return _arrMethods[mid];
    }               
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you use the method http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29 to directly get the method if available and let the JVM do the job efficiently for you?

BTW, the documentation of getMethods says: "The elements in the array returned are ***not sorted*** and are ***not in any particular order***". The binary search needs sorted data. That means you first need to sort the array.

NOTE: you should have a look to that method [getMatchingAccessibleMethod](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/v1.8.3/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/MethodUtils.html#getMatchingAccessibleMethod%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%5B%5D%29) that probably does what you expect.

Comment: This will only work for *public* methods. For those it sounds like a reasonable way to do it.

Comment: is there any way to do this without knowing the paramaters that the method takes? All I have is the string name of the method I am looking for.

Comment: If I get the list of paramaters, is there any way get their classes from it in an array to pass to 'getMethod()'? One solution I am experimenting with is: 
  Class _arrParameterClasses[];
  for (Object _oParameters: _arrParameters ){
   Class parameterClass = _oParameters.getClass();
   _arrParameterClasses.add(parameterClass);
  }

  foundMethod = cl.getMethod(_szMethodName, _arrParameterClasses); (is there a better way to follow up a comment with a block of code?)

Comment: This is not that easy because of polymorphism. If you have a method `sort(Collection c)` and you call it with `sort(new ArrayList<>())`, the getMethod("sort", new Class[]{ArrayList.class}) will not return anything, but it will work if the method invocation parameters match exactly the declared arguments. see my note